# Woocommerce: set featured image by image URL in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce product page that I'm adding/updating products everyday by a cronjob that consumes API's but I don't know how to set Featured Image by URL image on each product. This is a simple code that I have right now to add/update products after consuming the API

```
foreach ($products->generic_products as $product) {
        $post_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($product->id);
        if($post_id){
            $new_product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        }else{
            $new_product = new WC_Product;
            $new_product->set_sku($product->id);
        }
        $new_product->set_name($product->name);
        $new_product->set_status("publish");
        $new_product->set_price($product->price);
        $new_product->set_regular_price($product->price);
        $new_product->set_sale_price($product->price);
        $new_product->set_description($product->description);
        $new_product->save();
    }
```

How can I set a feature image by an URL? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Featured Image as a WordPress Core feature.

```
set_post_thumbnail( $product->ID, $image->ID );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail/